# Error: local variable referenced before assignment in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, python-toolbox, unboundlocalerror

I have a directory with contain others subdirectory with shapefiles.
I access to the **shapefiles** using a for, but then when I ned to use the variable **shape** that I get this message:

*UnboundLocalError: local variable 'shape' referenced before assignment*

```
 def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    """The source code of the tool."""

    fd= parameters[0].valueAsText
    raster= parameters[1].valueAsText
    out_CRS=arcpy.Describe (raster).spatialReference

    out= "Z:\\EMSV-057_AOIs_Reshape\\5_Process\\1_TaskA\\ModelBuilder\\MB_pruebas.gdb"
#-------------------------
    

#leemos los shapes de la carpeta
    for i in os.listdir(fd):
        for entry in os.listdir(fd +"\\"+i):
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(fd, entry)):
                if entry.endswith(".shp"):
                    shape= fd +"\\"+i+"\\"+entry


# Cogemos datos alfanumericos del AOI y el CRS del raster
            desc = arcpy.Describe(shape)

            shape_CRS=arcpy.Project_management(shape, desc.path + "\\" + desc.baseName + 
            "_REprj.shp", out_CRS)


        # Recortar-clip
            clip=arcpy.Clip_management(raster, "#", out+"\\" +"clip", shape_CRS, "0", 
            "ClippingGeometry","MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
```

Comment: @BERA, ```i``` is the name of each subdidirectory. Maybe is a better way to access to the shapefiles. When I use ```os.path.join``` I can use more than two elements? e.g, ```os.path.join(fd,i, entry)```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is telling you that the variable `shape` has not been assigned/created when you are trying to use it. So your code probably never reach this line: `shape= fd +"\\"+i+"\\"+entry`, possibly do to invalid paths or that you have no shapefiles in the directory.

To avoid your code breaking you can add an if statement to check if the variable exists: [How do I check if a variable exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists) before trying to use it.

Try using os.walk instead and combine path+filename with `os.path.join`s:

```
import os

fd = r'/home/bera/GIS/Data/'
filelist = []
for root,folder,files in os.walk(fd):
    for file in files:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root,file)) and file.lower().endswith('.shp'):
            filelist.append(os.path.join(root,file))

for f in filelist:
    print(f)

/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/lines.shp
/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/full_paths.shp
/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/a.shp
/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/overlaps2.shp
/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/grids/Second.shp
/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/grids/Firstfile.shp
```

Comment: Like the answer, it cuts straight to the heart of the problem and simplifies the code considerably. As much as I like os.walk the arcpy.da.Walk(fd,datatype='FeatureClass') could be more efficient, skipping over non spatial file types but still traversing the whole tree; the only downside is if there are a bunch of geodatabases or XLS in subfolders that you're not interested in, they will still get traversed. There is a potential problem with the file.endswith statement, if the file is 'FileName.Shp' then endswith('.shp') returns False, perhaps file.lower().endswith('.shp') would be better.